# Problems with C# coding in Unity for a specific project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple game for a school project using Unity. The purpose of the game is to control a ball and pick up coins. The game has 3 scenes. I have written some code in C# to count my pick up coins and set a condition to check if all coins are picked up, if so, a wintext appears at the center of the screen.

It works just fine for the first scene (lvl1) but not for the other 2.
All 3 scenes have a different number of coins. C# is new to me and I have tried various combinations but it hasn't worked.

How do I re-write this code so that the wintext appears after I pick up the right number of coins on every scene/level?

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    public Text countText;
    public Text winText;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private int count;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        count = 0;
        SetCountText();
        winText.text = "";
    
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            SetCountText();
  
        }
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Coins: " + count.ToString();
        if (count >= 2)
        {
            winText.text = "You Win!";
        }
       
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say it does not work on the other scenes do you mean that after picking up 2 coins it fires up the win text?

Comment: I actually have 88 coins on the first scene, 32 on the second and 31 on the third. I just set at 2 coins so I wouldn't have to complete the whole level just to see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a new public variable

```
...
public float speed;
public Text countText;
public Text winText;
public int numberOfCoinsToWin;
...
```

remember to set this new value in the editor for each scene

Use the variable in your condition.

```
if (count >= numberOfCoinstoWin)
{
    winText.text = "You Win!";
}
```

Sounds like you're lacking a very basic understanding of C# and programming in general. Here are somethings you could research to make life easier for you:

- variables
- control flow
- access modifiers
- classes (in computer science)
- object orientation

Also using Unity to learn C# is not great. You will miss a lot of fundamentals. I suggest learning C# without unity for a week or 2 and coming back.

Comment: Just to add something to what storm is saying, if im not mistaken with unity u actually need to set the variables as [Serializable] in order to be able to set them up from the editor

Comment: Only if their private. if they're public variables they are already serializable. Hence why I suggested that the OP researches access modifiers.

Comment: No if you make a class, you need to mark it as [Serializable] like nalnpir said, unless you refer to scriptableobjects, but that's another story. You are talking about [SerializeField], which is indeed for making private variables show up in the inspector.

Comment: @StormMuller, C# isn't a part of my curricular. We are having a 1-month course in Unity at the moment but I'm starting with Java next week. Again, thank you very much =)

Comment: @Immorality It's a monobehaviour you do not need to mark it as serializable

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet would dynamically set win condition based on scene, however it would be better if the scene could hold `coinToCollect` variable.

```
void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Coins: " + count.ToString();
    int coinsToCollect = 0;
    switch( /* get current scene here */)
    {
        case "scene1": // repeat for other scenes
            coinsToCollect = 2;
            break;
    }
    if (count >= coinsToCollect)
    {
        winText.text = "You Win!";
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually have 88 coins on the first scene, 32 on the second and 31 on the third. I just set at 2 coins so I wouldn't have to complete the whole level just to see if it works.What do you mean by coinToCollect?

Comment: coinsToCollect would act as the amount of coins you need to collect for each scene to set the win condition

Comment: what exactly do I need to write between the switch parameters and do I need to add something more somewhere else?

Comment: void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Coins: " + count.ToString();
        int coinsToCollect = 0;
        switch (robs_scene_lvl1)
        {
            case "robs_scene_lvl1": // repeat for other scenes
                coinsToCollect = 88;
                break;
            case "rahils_scene_lvl2":
                coinsToCollect = 32;
                break;
            case "jonas_scene_lvl3":
                coinsToCollect = 31;
                break;
        }
        if (count >= coinsToCollect)
        {
            winText.text = "You Win!";
       }
}

Comment: using a switch statement is just making you life difficult for no reason

Comment: I didn't work that much with unity apart some custom movement logic when I helped my friend. I don't know if scenes are treated as objects and if they can have variables, but as I said in my answer it would be better to have the win condition coins inside the scene, so the player could check directly from the scene he is in.